# Combine unknown sub-arrays of objects from an array of objects and filter it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

a simpler way to re-create the output of this code, where if sub arr0 is not null, it then combines it and filter desired output by the key `code`.

Thank you in advance!

```js
let array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'stuff1',
    arr0: [
      {id:1, code: 'imacode1'},
      {id:2, code: 'imacode2'},
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'stuff2',
    arr0: [
      {id:3, code: 'imacode3'},
      {id:4, code: 'imacode4'},
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'stuff3',
    arr0: []
  }
]
let arr = [];

for(let i of array){
  if(i.arr0.length !== 0){
    arr.push(i.arr0)   
  }
}
arr = arr.flat()
for(let j of arr){
  if(j.code === 'imacode2'){
    let code = arr.filter(j=>j.code!=='imacode2')
    code = code.map(({code}) => code)
    console.log(code)
  }
}
```

edit: added snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You oan use [Array.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) along with with [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the result you wish, first we use .flatMap() to create an array including all items in each arr0.

We then use .filter() to only include the desired items, using a custom (modifiable) filter function, in this case removing any item with a code of 'imacode2'.

```js
let array = [ { id: 1, text: 'stuff1', arr0: [ {id:1, code: 'imacode1'}, {id:2, code: 'imacode2'}, ] }, { id: 2, text: 'stuff2', arr0: [ {id:3, code: 'imacode3'}, {id:4, code: 'imacode4'}, ] }, { id: 3, text: 'stuff3', arr0: [] } ]

// Change filter as desired..
const filterProc = ({id, code}) => code !== 'imacode2';
const result = array.flatMap(el => el.arr0 || []).filter(filterProc).map(({code}) => code);
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it works thanks, and to get the result for only the code i just added in another map like so, var x = result.map(({code})=>code)

Comment: I'll update the answer too!